# How to test components being rendered when the redux store is changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have the below component- PLoad.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from '../../../components/UI/Spinner/Spinner';
import { getLoad } from '../../../store/actions/poe';
import Load from '../../../components/apps/P/Load';

const PLoad = ({ dispatchGetLoad, loadD, loading }) => {
    return (loading ? <Spinner /> :
    <div>
        <Load loadD={loadD} />
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   loadD: state.p.loadD,
   loading: state.p.loading
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   dispatchGetLoad: () => dispatch(getLoad())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PLoad);
```

I am trying to test this component using Jest+Enzyme -- PLoad.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import PLoad from '../PLoad';
import store from '../../../../store';
import Load from '../../../../components/apps/P/Load';
import Spinner from '.././../../../components/UI/Spinner/Spinner';

describe('PLoad component', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeAll(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PLoad />
        </Provider>);
   });

  it('should render the Load and Spinner components', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(Spinner)).toHaveLength(1); //this is passed
    expect(wrapper.find(Load)).toHaveLength(1); //ended in error
  });
});
```

NOTE:- store.js used in the above PLoad.test.js is the actual store.js used by my app.
I want to test when the loading: false, PLoad renders LoadD and when its true it renders Spinner.
loading is from the state of the redux store. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try dispatching an action to change loading flag in state which will trigger render of the component.

```
it('should render the Load components', () => {
    ---- dispatch action -------
    expect(wrapper.find(Load)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes...It is possible. The component gets whatever data you are passing to the provider. Pass an initialState object to store with `loading:false`. In fact you can create helper method with all the store creation logic in a separate file and reuse it in every connected component.